# How to get attribute name ,value and its tag name and value of a complex nested xml in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

Hi I have a complex big and nested xml that i have to parse and inset into database .
I have done it using JAVA X path but it is very slow .

Is there any way to get all attribute name and value and also tag name and value of the below xml .
Here is my xml .
Just add up more information  `contentSet` repeats and also child tag `MentalSeriesStatements` also repeats .

```
<evn:Body mVer="0.0" mjVe="1" contentSet="Mental">
<evn:Operation action="Edit">
<evn:Data si:type="al:MentalPeriodDataItem">

<al:MentalSeriesPeriod mentalSeriesPeriodIndex="33" mentalSeriesPeriodType="HalfYear" mentalSeriesPeriodEndDate="20000930T00:00:00+00:00">

<al:MentalSeriesId objectType="MentalSeries" objectTypeId="7428374">23984623874</al:MentalSeriesId>

<al:UniqueMentalSet objectType="Mental" objectTypeId="404084">48433426923</al:UniqueMentalSet>

<al:MentalSeriesStatements>


<al:MentalSeriesStatement effectiveTo="20000930T00:00:00+00:00" effectiveFrom="20000330T00:00:00+00:00">
<al:MentalSeriesStatementTypeCode>BAL</al:MentalSeriesStatementTypeCode>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementPeriodId>137</al:MentalSeriesStatementPeriodId>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementSourceId>55</al:MentalSeriesStatementSourceId>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementCurrencyId objectType="Currency" objectTypeId="404014">500186</al:MentalSeriesStatementCurrencyId>
<al:IsUsedForAnalytics>true</al:IsUsedForAnalytics>
</al:MentalSeriesStatement>

<al:MentalSeriesStatement effectiveTo="20000930T00:00:00+00:00" effectiveFrom="20000330T00:00:00+00:00">
<al:MentalSeriesStatementTypeCode>CAS</al:MentalSeriesStatementTypeCode>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementPeriodId>39</al:MentalSeriesStatementPeriodId>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementSourceId>55</al:MentalSeriesStatementSourceId>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementCurrencyId objectType="Currency" objectTypeId="404014">500186</al:MentalSeriesStatementCurrencyId>
<al:IsUsedForAnalytics>true</al:IsUsedForAnalytics>
</al:MentalSeriesStatement>

<al:MentalSeriesStatement effectiveTo="20000930T00:00:00+00:00" effectiveFrom="20000330T00:00:00+00:00">
<al:MentalSeriesStatementTypeCode>FTN</al:MentalSeriesStatementTypeCode>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementPeriodId>39</al:MentalSeriesStatementPeriodId>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementSourceId>55</al:MentalSeriesStatementSourceId>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementCurrencyId objectType="Currency" objectTypeId="404014">500186</al:MentalSeriesStatementCurrencyId>
<al:IsUsedForAnalytics>true</al:IsUsedForAnalytics>
</al:MentalSeriesStatement>

<al:MentalSeriesStatement effectiveTo="20000930T00:00:00+00:00" effectiveFrom="20000330T00:00:00+00:00">
<al:MentalSeriesStatementTypeCode>INC</al:MentalSeriesStatementTypeCode>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementPeriodId>39</al:MentalSeriesStatementPeriodId>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementSourceId>55</al:MentalSeriesStatementSourceId>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementCurrencyId objectType="Currency" objectTypeId="404014">500186</al:MentalSeriesStatementCurrencyId>
<al:IsUsedForAnalytics>true</al:IsUsedForAnalytics>
</al:MentalSeriesStatement>

<al:MentalSeriesStatement effectiveTo="20000930T00:00:00+00:00" effectiveFrom="20000330T00:00:00+00:00">
<al:MentalSeriesStatementTypeCode>SHE</al:MentalSeriesStatementTypeCode>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementPeriodId>39</al:MentalSeriesStatementPeriodId>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementSourceId>55</al:MentalSeriesStatementSourceId>
<al:MentalSeriesStatementCurrencyId objectType="Currency" objectTypeId="404014">500186</al:MentalSeriesStatementCurrencyId>
<al:IsUsedForAnalytics>true</al:IsUsedForAnalytics>
</al:MentalSeriesStatement>

</al:MentalSeriesStatements>

</al:MentalSeriesPeriod>
</evn:Data>
```

Here is my sample code

```
String SeriesPeriodExpression ="/path[@action='"+strAction+"']/Data[@type='"+DataType+"']/mentalSeriesPeriod";
SeriesPeriodExpressionList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(mentalSeriesPeriodExpression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

 String SeriesIdExpr =SeriesPeriodExpression+"/SeriesId";
 NodeList SeriesIdList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(SeriesIdExpr).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

 String SeriesId_objectTypeIdExpr =SeriesPeriodExpression+"/SeriesId/@objectTypeId";
 NodeList SeriesId_objectTypeIdExprList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(SeriesId_objectTypeIdExpr).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

 String SeriesId_objectTypeExpr =SeriesPeriodExpression+"/SeriesId/@objectType";
 NodeList SeriesId_objectTypeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(SeriesId_objectTypeExpr).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

 for (int i = 0; i < SeriesPeriodExpressionList.getLength(); i++) {
     String SeriesId = "";
     String SeriesId_objectTypeId ="";
     String SeriesId_objectType ="";

     if(SeriesIdList.getLength()==SeriesPeriodExpressionList.getLength()){
         SeriesId = SeriesIdList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
         sbSeriesPeriod.append(SeriesIdList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue() + "~");
     }

     if(SeriesId_objectTypeIdExprList.getLength()==SeriesPeriodExpressionList.getLength()){
         SeriesId_objectTypeId = SeriesId_objectTypeIdExprList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
         sbSeriesPeriod.append(SeriesId_objectTypeId + "~");
     }

     if(SeriesId_objectTypeList.getLength()==SeriesPeriodExpressionList.getLength()){
          SeriesId_objectType = SeriesId_objectTypeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
         sbSeriesPeriod.append(SeriesId_objectType + "~");
     }


     String SeriesStatementsExpression ="/ContentEnvelope/Body/ContentItem[@action='"+strAction+"']/Data[@type='"+DataType+"']/SeriesPeriod[@fundamentalSeriesPeriodIndex='"+SeriesPeriod_fundamentalSeriesPeriodIndex+"'][@fundamentalSeriesPeriodEndDate='"+SeriesPeriod_fundamentalSeriesPeriodEndDate+"'][./SeriesId ='"+SeriesId+"']/SeriesStatements/SeriesStatement";
     NodeList SeriesStatementsList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(SeriesStatementsExpression).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
     System.out.println(SeriesStatementsList.getLength());
     String SeriesStatementTypeCodeExpr =SeriesStatementsExpression+"/SeriesStatementTypeCode";
     NodeList SeriesStatementTypeCodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(SeriesStatementTypeCodeExpr).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

     String SeriesStatementPeriodIdExpr =SeriesStatementsExpression+"/SeriesStatementPeriodId";
     NodeList SeriesStatementPeriodIdList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(SeriesStatementPeriodIdExpr).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

     String SeriesStatementSourceIdExpr =SeriesStatementsExpression+"/SeriesStatementSourceId";
     NodeList SeriesStatementSourceIdList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(SeriesStatementSourceIdExpr).evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

     for (int k = 0; k < SeriesStatementsList.getLength(); k++) {
        String SeriesStatementTypeCode ="";
        String SeriesStatementPeriodId = "";
        String SeriesStatementSourceId = "";

            if(UniqueSet_objectTypeIdList.getLength()==SeriesStatementsList.getLength()){
            SeriesStatementTypeCode = SeriesStatementTypeCodeList.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
        }
        if(SeriesStatementPeriodIdList.getLength()==SeriesStatementsList.getLength()){
            SeriesStatementPeriodId = SeriesStatementPeriodIdList.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); 
        }
        if(SeriesStatementSourceIdList.getLength()==SeriesStatementsList.getLength()){
            SeriesStatementSourceId = SeriesStatementSourceIdList.item(k).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(); 
        }

            }
```

}

Comment: Can you show the current code you are using to get this data?

Comment: I am using javax path to get this data .Calculating NodeList and then looping through all the nodes inside again for each al:MentalSeriesStatements i am calculating the Node list and looping again to get the correct records .But this is very .I have 276 items in my main Node list and then for each item 15 items so it takes 5 minutes to  get all values .I will keep sample code also .

Comment: @Ray i have added the sample code ..